# How to create empty file before downloading a file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

You know some download manager allocate free space as much as download file size before downloading file such advance download manger. It allocate free space before downloading. So how to make file and allocate free space as desired download file size in android java?

Comment: no ... i can't figure out what to do..!!

Comment: I would recommend you to read before putting that in your implementations. Please go through these links, It will provide you the way how we can read/write a file.
1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-class-in-java/

There are many more on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using Java, hopefully it would point you in the right direction.

```
        File outputDirectory = new File(directoryPath + "\\FILENAME");
    if (!outputDirectory.exists()){
        outputDirectory.mkdir();
    }
```

The directory path in my case is used when a user assigns directly a path toward a directory, within it the program checks if the folder (which you can name whatever you like) exists, and if it does not it simply creates it.

Within you case you can simply go ahead, run the code and see if within your app the folder "download" (or other name) exists and if it does not simply to create it.

Should work

Comment: I asked how create empty file  just like  advanced download manager does not to create a folder which doesn’t exist...

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating empty file using this function in my existing project, may be it can help you out.

```
public File createImageFile(Context context) {
    File image = null;
    try {
        // Create an image file name
        String name= Global.IMAGE_NAME;
        File storageDir = context.getFilesDir();
        image = File.createTempFile(
                name,  // prefix
                Global.IMAGE_JPG_EXTENSION,        // suffix 
                storageDir      // directory 
        );
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AppLogger.exception(getTag(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return image;
}
```